# Multiple Jquery-Ajax calls for inserting and fetching data is making website to freeze

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am using 2 different jquery ajax calls to insert and fetch data at the same time.

For example, one html page is inserting data in a table at a rapid rate somewhere 30 insertions per second.
While another html page is fetching the inserted data to display.

Below is the jquery call to insert the data :

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test.com/insertsentence',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            Msid: "rpandey",
            Verbatim: hypos[0].transcript
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('insertion success...');
            console.log('hypos[0].transcript - ',hypos[0].transcript);
            console.log('insertion data ---',data);
           // alert('Data: ' + data);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Error in Insertion: " + JSON.stringify(request));
            cosole.log("Error in Insertion: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
```

This is the code i am using to fetch the data

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function myTimeoutFunction() {
        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://test.com/unoapi/GetLastViewedTextDetails',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
               // alert('DataFetched: ' + data);

                createUserLastChat(data);
                $("#msg_history").animate({ scrollTop: $('#msg_history').prop("scrollHeight") }, 1000);

            },
            error: function (request, error) {
               // alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(request));
            }
        });
    }

    myTimeoutFunction();
    var counter = setInterval(myTimeoutFunction, 3000);

});
```

This function is getting called again and again via SetInterval().

But this code is derailing the website and freezing it completely after few minutes.

Adding new code below for createUserLastChat() function.

```
function createUserLastChat(jsonOBJ) {
    var jsonObj = jsonOBJ;

    console.log(_.groupBy(jsonObj, 'Speaker'));

    var result = _.chain(jsonObj).groupBy('Speaker').map(function (value, key) {
        return {

            Name: key,
            Comment: sum(value)["Sentence"],
            Date: sum(value)["CreatedDate"]
        };
    }).value();
    console.log('Left Object -' + JSON.stringify(result));

    for (var j = 0; j < jsonObj.length; j++) {

        var secondResult = `<div class="incoming_msg">
                            <div class="incoming_msg_img"> `+ jsonObj[j].Speaker + `:</div>
                            <div class="received_msg">
                                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                                    <p>
                                        `+ jsonObj[j].Sentence + `
                                    </p>
                                    <span class="time_date" style="float:right;">` + jsonObj[j].CreatedDate + `</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
        $("#msg_history").append(secondResult);
    }

}
```

Is there any other way of handling multiple calls in JQUERY.

Comment: Where is your `clearInterval()` to stop the loading once all the data is there?

Comment: i have not added that yet but do i need to do that.
I mean I need to refresh the contents after every 3 seconds hence do i still need it ?

Comment: Study `SignalR` and `SqlDependency` classes for a better experience.

Comment: @Rishabh sounds like you are checking for new chat messages. So you may not need it for a 'heartbeat' type of action. Please provide an example of the Data being returned. I would expect it's a smaller amount of data since you're just getting the most recent update, correct?

Comment: @JamshaidKamran thanks for suggestion, so r u talking about SqlDependency class in .Net

Comment: @Twisty yep you got it right . That is what iam trying to show. Also, the data returned is nothing but an array of strings. There is a sql procedure which returns the data.

Comment: @Rishabh assuming you are appending to an existing table or display of existing chat messages, it would be helpful to see all relevant code, including your `createUserLastChat();`I suspect there is something causing a delay or something waiting longer for the server to respond maybe.

Comment: @Twisty  please find the edited code snippet which includes ```createUserLastChat()```.